# Is there such a thing as foundations of philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, foundations

In many subjects, like math and physics, there is also the foundations of that subjects, like foundations of math and foundations of physics, respectively. Is there also such a thing as the foundations of philosophy? If so, can I see some papers and books on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the foundations of philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/29160/what-are-the-foundations-of-philosophy)

Comment: I usually start with metaphysics, epistemology, logic, and axiology as the main "foundational" branches, and then I work my way into sub-branches: such as, aesthetics, morality, ethics, politics, etc. within axiology.

Comment: It is hard to believe: basically phil is concerned with foundational issues...